# How to compare hours and minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I would like to check if the user has logged into site on time or late suppose the user have to login before 10:15 and he log in at 11:00

how can i just know if he is late or early or on time?

should i use strtotime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of strtotime function which returns the Current Time as a Unix Timestamp.

Compare the two values to check if he/she has logged in late or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
getTimeDifference(10:15,11:00)

 function getTimeDifference($dtime,$atime)
                    {

                     $nextDay=$dtime>$atime?1:0;
                     $dep=EXPLODE(':',$dtime);
                     $arr=EXPLODE(':',$atime);
                     $diff=abs(MKTIME($dep[0],$dep[1],0,DATE('n'),DATE('j'),DATE('y'))-MKTIME($arr[0],$arr[1],0,DATE('n'),DATE('j')+$nextDay,DATE('y')));
                     $hours=FLOOR($diff/(60*60));
                     $mins=FLOOR(($diff-($hours*60*60))/(60));
                     $secs=FLOOR(($diff-(($hours*60*60)+($mins*60))));
                     IF(STRLEN($hours)<2){$hours="0".$hours;}
                     IF(STRLEN($mins)<2){$mins="0".$mins;}
                     IF(STRLEN($secs)<2){$secs="0".$secs;}
                     //RETURN $hours.':'.$mins.':'.$secs;
                     return $hours.':'.$mins;
                    }
```

Comment: So many errors! The inbuilt functions you've used are lowercase (`ABS` should be `abs`), also declaring and calling the functions doesn't work like that. Please check your code before posting, and ideally explain what it's doing too.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$timeString="your time string"

$currTime = strtotime($timeString)
$inTime = strtotime("06/01/2017 11:00AM")

$early=($currTime >= $inTime)
```

Comment: Why is $early an array?